# window.setTimeout in javascript link on Firefox not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, hyperlink

Due to generic reasons I have to put some javascript into the HREF attributes of some navigation bar links to perform some more actions. Partially actions require delayed execution, thus I'm using `window.setTimeout`.

Here is a sample:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('do anything');window.setTimeout(function(){alert('do anything else');},1111);">Login</a>
```

In Google Chrome this works like expected, but on Firefox it redirects to a new empty page that contains only a random number when `window.setTimeout` is called.

Preview: http://jsbin.com/rekosahute

Why this is happening and how I can avoid that and still using HREF attributes for such actions? Specially the returned number is magic to me.

Comment: You don't need to write `window` when you want to access functions in the window objects, they're always accesible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in an anonymous function seems to fix it:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){alert('do anything');window.setTimeout(function(){alert('do anything else');},1111);})()">Login</a>
```

The number that is returned and displayed on the page in FF, is the return value of window.setTimeout, it's a counter incremented every time it is called, to allow you keep track of timers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you, this works. You picked the right question and deserve the rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way...

```
<a href="javascript: alert('do anything');
     window.setTimeout(
       function() {
        alert('do anything else');
        }, 1111
     );
    void 0">
Login
</a>
```